# Definition of being smooth of relative dimension in Vakil

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

In the July3123 version of Algebraic geometry book by Vakil, he defined the notion of smooth of relative dimension in 13.6. I will write down the definition first:

**Definition.** A morphism $\pi:X\to Y$ is smooth of relative dimension $n$ if there exists open covers $\{U_i\}$ of $X$ and $\{V_i\}$ of $Y$ such that $\pi(U_i)\subseteq V_i$ and the diagram commutes
\begin{array}{}
U_i & \xrightarrow{\cong} & W& \xrightarrow{open} \operatorname{Spec}B[x_1,\ldots,x_{n+r}]/(f_1,\ldots,f_r)\\
\downarrow & &\downarrow_{\rho|_W}&\swarrow_{\rho}\\
V_i&\xrightarrow{\cong}&\operatorname{Spec}B
\end{array}
where $\rho$ comes from the obvious ring map and $W$ is an open subscheme, such that the determinant $det(\frac{\partial{f_j}}{\partial{x_i}})_{i,j\leq r}$ of the Jacobian of the $f_i$'s with respect to the $x_i$'s is an invertible function on $W$.

**My question.**

1. I tried to verify that $\mathbb{A}^n_B\to \operatorname{Spec}B$ is smooth of relative dimension $n$. So I cover $\operatorname{Spec}B$ by itself and $\mathbb{A}^n_B$ by the distinguished opens $D(f)$ where $f\in B[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Now I have such commutative diagram
   \begin{array}{}
   D(f) & \xrightarrow{\cong} &\operatorname{Spec}B[x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}=t]/(1-ft)& \xrightarrow{open} \operatorname{Spec}B[x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}]\\
   \downarrow & &\downarrow_{\rho|_W}&\swarrow_{\rho}\\
   \operatorname{Spec}B&\xrightarrow{\cong}&\operatorname{Spec}B
   \end{array}
   but the Jacobian matrix is $0$. So I replace the $\operatorname{Spec}B[x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}]$ by the distinguished open itself $\operatorname{Spec}B[x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}=t]/(1-ft)$. Now the Jacobian is still $0$ since now $r=1$, $f_1=1-ft$ and we only consider the partial derivatives wrt $x_1$. Of course, if we put $t$ in the first position, we would get $-f$, which is indeed a nowhere zero function on $D(f)$. But shouldn't this be independent of our choice?
2. I am not so sure how he concluded that the locus where $\pi$ is smooth of relative dimension $n$ is open, as such notion is not even defined on points. Am I missing something?
3. How do we actually show that any open embedding is etale? According to the definition, we need to locally embed our source into a finite type scheme  $\operatorname{Spec}B[x_1,\ldots,x_{r}]/(f_1,\ldots,f_r)$. Is that possible? I tried $\operatorname{Spec}B[x_1,\ldots,x_r]/(x_1,\ldots,x_r)$ but it seems too good to be true..

I apologize for the triviality as it seems to be simply playing around the definition. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You must explain the notation: Is $U_i$ an open subscheme of $Spec(B[x_1,..,x_{n+r}]/(f_j)$? Why do you use $W$?

Comment: @hm2020 Sorry for the confusion. $U_i$ is an open cover of $X$. There is an isomorphism taking it to $W$, which is an open subscheme of $Spec(B[x_1,\cdots,x_{n+r}]/(f_1,\cdots,f_r))$. That is what I understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me if I make any mistakes. I am also reading the note by Vakil.

1.I think to have $\mathbb{A}^n_B\to \text{Spec} B$ smooth of relative dimension $n$, we just need to take itself as a cover for **both** $\mathbb{A}^n_B$ and $\text{Spec} B$, where $\mathbb{A}^n_B=\text{Spec}B[x_1,...,x_{n+1}]/x_1$.

Also, you mention that this should be independent of the choice. I am not sure but I don't see any reason for the commutative diagram to be unique.

I think it's just like the definition of locally free sheaves: we need to make **some** choice of covering where the sheaf is free on every piece. This doesn't mean it holds for **every** choice of covering.

2.I don't think he gives the definition of the locus of etaleness. Probably we can mimic the definition of the locus where two morphisms agree. For example, let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism. The locus of etaleness of $f$ is a locally closed subscheme $i:Z\to X$ where $f\cdot i$ is etale, and for every morphism $g:W\to X$ with $f\cdot g$ etale, $g$ uniquely factors through $i$.

I am not sure how to show that such a locus is open though.

3.Let $U\to X$ be an open embedding. Pick any affine open cover $\{\text{Spec}(B_i)\}_i$ of $X$. The intersection of $U$ with $\text{Spec}(B_i)$ is the union of $\{\text{Spec}(B_{f_{i,j}})\}_j$. Form the new cover $\{\text{Spec}(B_{f_{i,j}})\}_{i,j}$ of $U$, where every piece is an open subscheme of $\text{Spec}(B_i[x]/x)$. This shows that $i$ is etale.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It feels still a bit weird to me since one needs to make many choices in this definition, e.g. open covers and open embeddings...

Comment: +1, good answer. For #2, let me make one suggestion: one may say that a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is smooth of relative dimension $n$ at a point $x\in X$ if there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ so that the diagram holds. Now openness is immediate: just use the same neighborhood for all points in that neighborhood!

Comment: @KReiser Thank you! So I consider the locus $X_n$ where $\pi$ is smooth of relative dimension $n$ and take a point $p\in X_n$. The definition gives us an open neighborhood $U$ you mentioned. Also it is saying that $\pi$ is smooth of relative dimension $n$ at every point in this open neighborhood $U$. Hence $U\subseteq X_n$, which means $X_n$ is open. Is this correct?

Comment: @Mizutsuki essentially, yes.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 2**: "I am not so sure how he concluded that the locus where π is smooth of relative dimension n is open, as such notion is not even defined on points. Am I missing something?"

This is a partial answer: If $g:= Jac(f_i)$ is the determinant of the jacobian matrix, it follows the basic open set $D(g) \subseteq Spec(B[x_1,..,x_{n+r}]/(f_1,..,f_r)$ is smooth over $Spec(B)$ by definition, since it is "the locus where $Jac(f_i)$ is a unit".

You find some results on "formal smoothness" in EGA-IV_4:

**Thm 22.5.8** Let $k$ be a field of char $p>0$ and let $A$ be a local noetherian $k$-algebra The following statements are equivalent:

(1) $A$ is formally smooth (in the "preadic topology").
(2) $A$ is geometrically regular over $k$.
(3) For each field extension $k \subseteq K$ with $k^p \subseteq K$ it follows $A\otimes_k K$ is regular.

Formal smoothness equals  "smoothness" for "finitely presented morphisms".
Formal smoothness is defined using "the infinitesimal lifting property" as in Matsumuras book.

The following statements are equivalent (see the "stacks project" Prop. 10.138.8 for a proof). Let $\phi: R \rightarrow S$ be a map of commutative unital rings.

(1) $S$ is formally smooth over $R$.

(2) The naive cotangent complex $NLS/R$ is quasi-isomorphic to a projective $S$-module placed in degree 0.

Hence yo may use the "naive cotangent complex" to check if a map is formally smooth.

**Question 3:** How do we actually show that any open embedding is etale? According to the definition, we need to locally embed our source into a finite type scheme  $\operatorname{Spec}B[x_1,\cdots,x_{r}]/(f_1,\cdots,f_r)$. Is that possible? I tried $\operatorname{Spec}B[x_1,\cdots,x_r]/(x_1,\cdots,x_r)$ but it seems too good to be true.."

**Answer:** If $S:=B[x_1]/(f_1)$ with $f_1:=-1+fx_1$ it follows $S \cong B_f$ and hence $i: D(f):=Spec(B_f) \rightarrow Spec(B)$ is an open immersion. The jacobian matrix is the following $1 \times 1$ matrix:

$$J(f_1):=(\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1})$$

and the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}:= f \in S^*$ which is a unit. Hence $det(J(f_1))$ is a unit. Hence a "basic open set" $D(f) \subseteq Spec(B)$ is smooth of relative dimension $0$ with the above definition.

Comment: Sorry but how should we construct $f_i$ for question 2? I think in this case we only have that $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism and want to determine the locus where $f$ is smooth of dimension $n$.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution to 2) is really cool. Also,@Ja_1941 I think Vakil mentioned the flaws of the definition after this definition, that is, we might not know the smoothness without given the "right" variables "$x_i$" and $"f_i"$.

Comment: @hm2020 I think by finding the locus, we should start with $f:X\to Y$ which is an arbitrary morphism and find the largest locally closed subscheme of $X$ where $f$ is smooth of relative dimension n, in which case we cannot apply the definition.

Comment: @Mizutsuki - is there a condition on the morphism $\pi$ for the locus where is is smooth of relative dimension $n$ to be open?

Comment: @hm2020 I guess Vakil means different things by locus that is smooth of relative dimension n and a map that is smooth of relative dimension n? If we assume the former notion is discussed over a smooth morphism of relative dimension n, then it is possible to use those $f_i$'s and Jacobian criterion to show the openness, as you did. As I stated, I am not very sure about what he means in the context.

Comment: @Mizutsuki - In Hartshorne the following is proved: If $k$ is an algebraically closed field and if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of non singular varieties over $k$, it follows $f$ is smooth of relative dimension $n$ iff $\Omega^1_{X/Y}$ is locally trivial of rank $n$. If there is an open nonempty subscheme $V \subseteq Y$ with $U:=f^{-1}(V)$ such that $\Omega^1_{U/V}$ is locally trivial, one can conclude the induced morphim $f_V: U \rightarrow V$ has the desired property.

Comment: Hence in this situation one has to prove there is such a nonempty subscheme using $\Omega^1_{X/Y}$. One needs something similar for $X$ and $Y$ defined over an arbitrary base $S$.

Comment: There are results in commutative algebra of the following form (EGA-IV_2, Lemme 6.9.2): If $A$ is a noetherian integral domain and $B$ an $A$-algebra of finite type and $M$ a finitely generated $B$-module, there is an $f\in A$ with $M_f$ a free $A$-module. Hence one has to assume $Y$ is integral and locally noetherian to conclude an open non empty $V$ to exist where $\Omega^1_{U/V}$ is locally trivial.

Comment: There are some results in Hartshorne (Lemma III.10.5, over a field of char $0$) - when you use the cotangent bundle $\Omega^1_{X/Y}$ you use the "first order derivative". And in char $p$ you may have to use "other methods".

Comment: Assume $k$ is algebraically closed and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a smooth morphism of "nonsingular varieties" of relative dimension $n$. It follows for any closed point $y \in Y$ (with residue field $\kappa(y) \cong k$) the induced cotangent bundle $\Omega^1_{X_y/k}$ is locally trivial. Hence the fiber $X_y$ is "smooth of relative dimension $dim(X_y)$" over $\kappa(y)$. Hence in general for an open subscheme $V \subseteq Y$ with $f_V: f^{-1}(V)\rightarrow V$ smooth of relative dimension $n$, this puts conditions on the fibers: All fiber must be smooth.

Comment: @hm2020 Waow, thank you so much for such detailed explannation and references. I have not reached the part introducing $\Omega^1$ yet. But I will try to take a peek at it and understand what is going on.